# How do I convert an image to PDF using IText 7 and keep the height and width the same in the PDF?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I've been trying to create a method that converts an image such as a BMP into a PDF and have the created PDF maintain the same dimentions.  For example If I look at the height and width of my BMP file in ms paint it is 0.87" Wide and 0.92" High. Unfortunately when looked at in adobe acrobat the height of the converted file is 1.15"Wide and 1.22" High.

I'm new to iText and have struggled with many of the examples being for older incompatible versions.

**Here is the code that I used to convert the image to PDF:**

```
public static byte[] convertImageBytesToPdfBytes(byte[] imgBytes) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream returnSM = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(returnSM);
        // Creating a PdfDocument
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        //PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(returnSM));
        // Creating an ImageData object
        ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(imgBytes);
        // Creating an Image object
        Image img = new Image(data);
        img.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        float imgWidth = img.getImageWidth();
        float imgHeight = img.getImageHeight();
        img.setFixedPosition(0, 0);         
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        PageSize pagesize = new PageSize(rect);
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(pagesize);
        // Creating a Document Document
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, pagesize);
        document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        // Adding image to the document
        document.add(img);
        // Closing the document
        document.close();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return returnSM.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Note: Height and width measured in inch or mm are very dependant on the PPI/DPI of the screen that is viewing it and the program that is displaying the image. Often it will be different sizes when opened in different software/computers. For example, many applications typically default to 96 DPI with is the Windows default, whereas Adobe acrobat on my PC defaults to 110 PPI, so when you check the size in inch or mm it will never match up. It's best to measure the image in PPI/DPI to get an accurate comparison.

Comment: Okay,  Using this info, I converted the same BMP to PDF using Adobe Acrobat So that I was comparing measurements using the same program. The results were encouraging.  The PDF converted with iText 7 showed 4.82 x 0.96 in while the one converted by Adobe Acrobat  showed 4.82 x 1.00 in. That may be close enough. Thank you for the response.